# Google store new rule Api 23 to 28 why Gradle Update error

Tags: java, android, api

I have app in different project. App api 23 everything on way but google new rule apply when api upgrade is one more error. How to fix the error?

***App Gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 110
    versionName "3.1.6"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation files('libs/volley.jar')

implementation project(':pulltorefresh-and-loadmore')

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.2.2'

implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2'

implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1' 
} apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***App in Project Gradle***

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}
}
android.libraryVariants
publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'com.costum.android.widget'
        artifactId 'pullandloadmore-aar'
        version '1.0'
        artifact source: file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "file:${projectDir}/maven-repo"
    }
}
}
```

***Project Gradle***

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    google()
}
}
```

Project rebuild or sync get this error

> Illegal char  at index 7: ....\l?brary_man?fest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

***All error***
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AgfA3XSEsn0HhtFHUMKZQN_tnCuo-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exact same error. I changed windows display language from Turkish to Englis(US) and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

check the `build.gradle` of module `:pulltorefresh-and-loadmore` - or the directory structure.
there is an illegal `i` or some other character, which looks alike an `i`; eg. `í`, `î` or `ì` ...in string `l?brary_man?fest`, which should be `library_manifest`. also switch the editor to `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: Yes rebuild project auto create path (pulltorefresh-and-loadmore\build\intermediates\ lıbrary_manıfest\debug) in AndroidManifest.xml but every rebuild this path (lıbrary_manıfest) recreate. where is change document encode format?

Comment: pulltorefresh-and-loadmore project add 

compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
    }

Build is succsefull but debug or run project continu problem

Comment: just search the whole project for `ı`to find the missing dot ... and convert all files to UTF-8.

Comment: @Mag try to search the root project; this has to come from somewhere. or try listing all files not `UTF-8` encoded with `find . -type f -exec file --mime {} \; | grep -v '.svn' | grep -v '.git' | grep -v "charset=utf-8"`

Comment: no result :( because of all file open with notpad ++ and change encoding type utf 8 with bom. I do not understand, may project debug, build and sync no problem api was 23. What is the change ?